# Performming I/O operation on azure function vs azure Blob Container

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a NodeJS app that does the following :

1. accept a zip file as an input.
2. extract the zip file,
   take all the PDF attachments out of it,
3. and merge them all into 1
   single PDF. (The final PDF is what matter and store the final PDF persistently on a local drive)

Everything is working fine locally. Now I am trying to run the same code in `Azure function` and save the final PDF in `Azure Blob Container`. I am wondering if Azure function is made for such file operation scenario?

If not, would it be possible to upload the zip file into Azure Storage Blob and let the nodejs app which is running on Azure Function to perform operation on them directly or the function must first download the zip file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

And I also suggest you use [blob trigger function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function#create-a-blob-storage-triggered-function)(as you mentioned that upload the zip file into Azure Storage Blob and let the nodejs app which is running on Azure Function to perform operation). When upload .zip file to blob storage, in your azure function, write the code to do the operations like unzip / merge.

But there is a [sandbox limitation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#win32ksys-user32gdi32-restrictions) for Windows UI functionality, you should avoid such operation if you current code uses it.